# ZF2 Stream with byte array

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i get an Byte Array from a REST API. Then I create a local file from this Byte Array. And I can send this file with ZF2 to the browser.

Code from within ZF2 controller action:

```
file_put_contents($fullpath, $rawPdf);
 $headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
 $contentDisposition = ($view == 'inline') ? 'inline': 'attachment';
 $headers->addHeaders(array(
    'Content-Disposition' => $contentDisposition . '; filename="' . basename($fullpath) . '"',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Length' => filesize($fullpath),
    'Expires' => '@0',
    'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate',
    'Pragma' => 'public'
 ));
$response = new \Zend\Http\Response\Stream();
$response->setStream(fopen($fullpath, 'r'));
$response->setStreamName(basename($fullpath));
$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->setHeaders($headers);
return $response;
```

But I will directly send the Byte Array to the browser without creating a local file.

How can I set stream ($response->setStream()) with Byte Array? How to create a resource with a Byte Array, but without creating a local file?

With plain old PHP I can do that:

```
$rawPdf = '';
array_walk($byteArray, function($value) use (&$rawPdf) {
    $rawPdf .= chr($value);
});
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Bericht.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
echo $rawPdf;
```

Comment: I think you have to do $response->setContent($rawPdf);

Comment: You can write a file in `php://output`and force download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified example of the code I use to export some data in a CSV file and download if automatically.

You can adapt it to fit what you want

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="csv_file.csv');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ($this->getData() as $data)
{
     fputcsv($file, $data);
}

fclose($file);
exit(0);
```